# Android Studio Start Failed Duplicate Component Key Exception

Tags: android, android-studio, gitlab, android-studio-3.0

I was trying to install the gitlab plugin in android studio. Unfortunately i have install gitlab project and gitlab 2020 plugin simultaneously. When my IDE restarts it is showing me this error:

[image]

My android studio is not starting. Help if anyone can.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved after spending almost 2 days. I have searched gitlab in my C drive and delete it from there and restart mu PC and Android studio.